# Pandas How to find duplicate row in group

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

everyone, I try to find duplicate row in double grouped DataFrame and I don't understand how to do it.

```
df_part[df_part.income_flag==1].groupby(['app_id', 'month_num'])['amnt'].duplicate()
```

For example df:

[image]

So I want to see something like this:

[image]

So, if I use thise code I see that there are two same value 'amnt' 0.387677 but in different month... it's information that i need

```
df_part[(df_part.income_flag==2) & df_part.duplicated(['app_id','amnt'], keep=False)].groupby(['app_id', 'amnt', 'month_num'])['month_num'].count().head(10)


app_id  amnt      month_num
0       0.348838  3            1
        0.387677  6            1
                  10           2
        0.426544  2            2
        0.475654  2            1
        0.488173  1            1
1       0.297589  1            1
                  4            1
        0.348838  2            1
        0.426544  8            3
Name: month_num, dtype: int64
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Use `df_part.groupby(['app_id', 'month_num']).count()`.

Comment: Do you need `df_part[(df_part.income_flag==2) & df_part.duplicated(['app_id','amnt','month_num'], keep=False)].groupby(['app_id', 'amnt', 'month_num'])['month_num'].count().head(10)` ?

Comment: added `month_num` to `duplicated`

Comment: @jezrael if I add month_num to duplicated, it's find duplicate in same month, but I need in different. So I already have tried to add one more condition    `df_part[(df_part.income_flag==2) & df_part.duplicated(['app_id','amnt'], keep=False) & ~df_part.duplicated(['month_num'], keep=False)].head(10)`    but it doesn't work

Comment: @IvanTimishenko - hmmm, I have your real data, so cannot test.

Comment: Mayube help  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need chain another mask by `&` for bitwise `AND` with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = (df_part[(df_part.income_flag==1) & df_part.duplicated(['app_id','amnt'], keep=False)]
        .groupby('app_id')['amnt']
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='duplicate_count'))
print (df)
   app_id  duplicate_count
0      12                2
1      13                3
```

Comment: Thanks for new way... but I still try to find solution... So, I need to find duplicate from different month. I've tried give more information in edited question

Comment: @IvanTimishenko - Hrad to know solution, because no column `income_flag` in sample data. Can you add expected output if `df_part.income_flag==2` ?

Comment: all row have ncome_flag=2 in sample data, it's doesnt matter. I've tried to explain more and i've edited question, check it please.